# I need to find something remotely vs I need to find something remote

Tags: american-english

Say I'm talking about finding a new job, and I say:

> "I'm tired of working for these 9 to 5 jobs I need something with more flexibility, something **remotely/remote**"

Which word would best fit that sentence? And why?

Answer (score 2):

Going by the title of your question, you want to know whether to use 'remote' or 'remotely'. The context for this, in your description, is that not having to work from an office will give you flexibility. I conclude from this that you would like the **job** that you're seeking to be something you can do from afar, or "remotely".

This is important because

> I need to find something remotely.

means that you need to find something from far away, or that your **job search** is what is remote, and not the job itself. If, for example, I were looking for a job in Singapore while living in Seattle, I would say that I'm trying to "find a job remotely".

> I need to find something remote.

This *could* mean that you're looking for a job that allows you the flexibility to do it from somewhere other than the office. I think this is what you're trying to say. 
I say "*could* mean", because it may just as well mean that you need to find something that is physically distant e.g. I need to find a cabin in the woods that is remote and discreet. The meaning would have to be inferred based on context.

The word remote also has other meanings and nuances, especially the one that the previous commenter has pointed out, which defines your location relative to client/company offices and doesn't necessarily mean you won't have a fixed workspace. If this is to be used in important job search conversations, I would suggest that you sacrifice brevity for the sake of clarity and say **"I need to find a job that lets me work remotely."**

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a wee bit confusing since it contrasts working hours (“9 to 5”) first with the poorly defined notion of “flexibility”, and second with something about remoteness.

But, reading between the lines, and based on your use of **bold emphasis**, I think you’re asking for a word to express the opposite of working in an office or other more-or-less formal, fixed workplace where all employees typically work together. Yes?

If so, then I’m not aware of any specific term, but I might express your question as follows:

> I’m tired of working in a regular office job. I need something where I can work from home.

Or the context, now that I’ve clarified it, could even allow:

> I’m tired of working in a regular office job. I need something with more flexibility.

And then working back in the other issues that your original mentioned, the following also becomes less precise (and so broader in scope, which you might want) but is still more coherent than your specific form of words

> I’m tired of the daily, 9-5 office grind. I need something with more flexible hours, and the ability to work away from the office from time to time.

As an aside, an increasingly commonly seen abbreviation in this area is “WFH”, meaning Working From Home. Another version replaces the F/From with A/At. So in a company that permits it, you might see someone mail their boss in the morning with a subject line saying simply “WFH”. Braver souls, in an even more tolerant workplace might even send emails with no body and the subject line saying: WFH [eom], the [eom] meaning “end of message”  Given all that, you might render your original as something like:

> I’m fed up with having to work in an office every day. I need a place where they’re cool with the occasional WFH day.

One final caution. In some contracting/consulting fields, “remote working” is a term of art (i.e. it has a fairly precise meaning within that field). Specifically it means performing contract work for the client at the contract engineering company’s premises rather than at the client’s.